# CSV Validation columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have code to check if a CSV file is correct. I would like to write idiomatic code to check if the columns are correct. I don't want to write in block check if we have got first line check columns.

```
CSV.foreach(@csv) { |person|
  first_name, last_name, person_id, email, title, phone, mobile, department, address, city = person[0..9]
  zip_code, state, country, manager_id =person[10..13]
  @managers << manager_id
  @persons << person_id

  validate = false unless validate_email(email)
  validate = false unless validate_first_name(first_name)
  validate = false unless validate_last_name(last_name)
  validate = false unless validate_person_id(person_id)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the CSV have headers or can you add them? If yes you can do `CSV.foreach(@csv, :headers => true)` and get the column values like `person['first_name']`. Then the checks at the end become

```
validate = false unless validate_email(person['email'])
```

That said, it seems like your entire validation at the end could be written as

```
validate_email(person['email']) && validate_first_name(person['first_name']) etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Michael's advice for `:headers => true`

But if you want to validate all of the named fields in your example and are aiming for DRY (though, admittedly, maybe a bit too clever for maintainability), you could use [Enumerable#inject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
CSV.foreach(@cvs, :headers => true) { |person|
  @managers << person[:manager_id]
  @persons << person[:person_id]

  # Array of columns to be validated
  validate_cols = [:first_name, :last_name, :person_id, :email, :title, :phone,
           :mobile, :department, :address, :city, :zip_code, :state,
           :country, :manager_id]

  valid = validate_cols.inject(true){|valid_sum, col|
    valid_sum && send("validate_#{col}", person[col])
  }
}
```

This assumes you have `validate_*` methods for every column named in the `validate_cols` array.